# How to include missing rows in sql return

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to do a query like this:

(Psuedocode)

```
SELECT 
  NAME, SUM(VALUE), MONTH 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE MONTH BETWEEN 12 MONTHS AGO AND NOW 
GROUP BY MONTH, NAME
```

The problem I am getting is that a name exists in a few of the months, but not all of the months, so if i filter this down to return the values for only one name, i sometimes get only 3 or 4 rows, rather than the 12 I expect to see.

My question is, is there a way to return rows, where it will still include the name, and month within the range, where the value would just be set to zero when I am missing the row from the previous result.

My first thought was to just union another select onto it, but I cant seem to get the logic to work to adhere to the group by, as well as the where clauses for limiting the names.

Comment: One simple way to do this is to create a months table and join to it.

Comment: @paqogomez although as per Gordon, noted that an additional cross join of the months to distinct names will be required to complete the OP's cross tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you have data for all months, you can take the following approach.  Generate all the rows (uses a `cross join`) then bring in the data you want:

```
select  m.month, n.name, sum(t.value)
from (select distinct month from table) m cross join
     (select distinct name from table) n left join
     table t
     on t.month = m.month and t.name = n.name
group by m.month, n.name;
```

This will return the missing sums as `NULL` values.  If you want zero, then use `coalesce(sum(t.value), 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like the following table to generate all the past 12 months as separate rows:

```
SELECT add_months(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'MONTH'), LEVEL - 1)   AS month_in_range
FROM  all_objects
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 1 + months_between(add_months(sysdate, -12), TRUNC (sysdate, 'MONTH'));
```

and then do an outer join between you table and this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a left outer join similar to @paqogomez 's comment. As my team is already maintaining a time table, its very easy to get the month list for an outer join.

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(VALUE), TIME.MONTH
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MONTH FROM TIME_TABLE 
      WHERE MONTH BETWEEN 12 MONTHS AGO AND NOW) TIME
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE ON (TIME.MONTH = TABLE.MONTH)
GROUP BY TIME.MONTH, NAME
```